# Getting "A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified" with CUDA application

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc

I am getting the following error when running `make` for my CUDA (v7.5) application:

```
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
```

I'm not sure why. After extensive Googling, it seems something is likely wrong with my Makefile. Here it is -- any ideas what might be causing the error? Thank you in advance!

```
CC = nvcc
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field
LFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -Llib $(shell pkg-config --libs libmongoc-1.0 libbson-1.0)
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude $(shell pkg-config --cflags libmongoc-1.0 libbson-1.0)
LIBS = -lgsl -lcblas
BIN = ./bin
OBJDIR = ./obj
OBJ = factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o positions/callPosition.o positions/putPosition.o \
      positions/position.o strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o strategies/optimizationStrategy.o \
      strategies/strategy.o factories/optimizerFactory.o optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o optimizers/optimizer.o \
      factories/dataParserFactory.o dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o dataParsers/dataParser.o \
      studies/study.o studies/smaStudy.o studies/emaStudy.o studies/rsiStudy.o \
      studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o

all: prepareData optimize

prepareData: src/prepareData.cu $(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BIN)/$@ src/prepareData.cu $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

optimize: src/optimize.cu $(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BIN)/$@ src/optimize.cu $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cu
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/lib/strategies $(OBJDIR)/lib/positions $(OBJDIR)/lib/factories $(OBJDIR)/lib/optimizers $(OBJDIR)/lib/dataParsers $(OBJDIR)/lib/studies
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<
clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJDIR)
```

And here is the full compiler output:

```
rm -rf ./bin ./obj
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o -c lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/callPosition.o -c lib/positions/callPosition.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/putPosition.o -c lib/positions/putPosition.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/position.o -c lib/positions/position.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o -c lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.o -c lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/strategy.o -c lib/strategies/strategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizerFactory.o -c lib/factories/optimizerFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o -c lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/optimizers/optimizer.o -c lib/optimizers/optimizer.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/dataParserFactory.o -c lib/factories/dataParserFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o -c lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/dataParser.o -c lib/dataParsers/dataParser.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/study.o -c lib/studies/study.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/smaStudy.o -c lib/studies/smaStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/emaStudy.o -c lib/studies/emaStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/rsiStudy.o -c lib/studies/rsiStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o -c lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o -c lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --device-c --compiler-options=-Wall,-O3,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./bin/prepareData src/prepareData.cu ./obj/lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o ./obj/lib/positions/callPosition.o ./obj/lib/positions/putPosition.o ./obj/lib/positions/position.o ./obj/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o ./obj/lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.o ./obj/lib/strategies/strategy.o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizerFactory.o ./obj/lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o ./obj/lib/optimizers/optimizer.o ./obj/lib/factories/dataParserFactory.o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/dataParser.o ./obj/lib/studies/study.o ./obj/lib/studies/smaStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/emaStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/rsiStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o -L/usr/local/lib -Llib -L/usr/local/lib -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 -lgsl -lcblas
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
make: *** [prepareData] Error 1
```

Note this started happening around the time I added `--device-c` (which some code changes require).

Comment: `--device-c` tells the compiler to create an object file. In the last line before the error you want to link and therefore should not have this flag. Try moving the flag to the `-c` in the command for the `%.o: %.cu` target.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I do this, I get errors like `nvlink info    : Function '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd' has address taken but no possible call to it`.

Comment: Does this result in a linking error or is it just an info?

Comment: Ah good observation. It actually results in an error as well: `nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd' in './obj/lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o'
make: *** [prepareData] Error 255`. And no binaries are built.

Comment: there is a problem around a function called `Strategy::backtest(double*, double, double)` You  either haven't defined this function, or you haven't compiled it, or you haven't linked it. There is no way to tell you more than that.

Comment: Seeing as we have a whole new question about the same makefile and the error being discussed in comments, I closed this as a duplicate of the new one.

Comment: It's declared in the [base header](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/include/strategies/strategy.cuh#L32) and the [child header](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/include/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cuh#L21) file and defined in the [child implementation](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cu#L17) file, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll add comments there.